# CodeIgniter4 - Redirect with data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I try to do this redirect in controller:

```
$this->getSession()->setFlashdata("error_controller", "Incorrect email or password");
return redirect()->route("login");
```

and this is in view:

```
<?php
    if($error_controller){
        echo "<div>" . $error_controller . "</div>";
    }else{
        echo "no-no";
    }
?>
```

In browser is printed `no-no`, which that means `error_controller` from `flashdata` not arrives to view.

How to redirect to `login` route with data?

Comment: Try `$_SESSION['error_controller']` instead of `$error_controller`. Flashdata is attached to the session, not passed into the View as if your Controller called `view` with its second, optional parameter to pass in data to be mapped to variables (i.e. `$error_controller`). If that's not the problem however, I do have another idea.

Comment: Try this one `session()->get('error_controller');`

Answer (score 1):

**Add this code in the Controller**

```
session()->setFlashData("error_controller","Incorrect email or password");

return redirect()->to(base_url('/login'));
```

**Add this code inside the view file**

```
 <?php

if(session()->has('error_controller'))
  echo "<div>" . session()->getFlashdata('error_controller') . "</div>";
    }else{
        echo "no-no";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it worked:

In Controller:

```
$validate = $this->validate([
   'firstname' => 'required',
   'lastname'  => 'required',
   'email'     => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
]);
```

Then I passed errors as array in view (in controller)

```
$data['validation'] = $this->validator;
return view( 'view_file', $data );
```

Then in View File:

```
<?= form_open(....) ?>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname">
  <?= ( isset($validation) && $validation->hasError('firstname')) ? $validation->getError('firstname'): ''; ?>
<?= form_close() ?>
```